# d3 stacked bar chart with unusual data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, stacked-chart

So I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart in D3. I've read all the tutorials, even implemented a simple stacked bar chart. But now, the problem is I have an unusual data set, which looks like this:

```
[
  { "count": 18, "predicted": "mon", "name": "A", "actual": "mon" },
  { "count": 14, "predicted": "tue", "name": "A", "actual": "tue" },
  { "count": 7, "predicted": "wed", "name": "B", "actual": "wed" },
  { "count": 1, "predicted": "tue", "name": "B", "actual": "wed" },
  { "count": 4, "predicted": "thur", "name": "B", "actual": "thur" },
  { "count": 1, "predicted": "wed", "name": "B", "actual": "thur" },
]
```

I want to create a stacked bar chart where values of `count` will be stacked for all `actual` values that are equal. How do I go about in doing this? I've scoured the internet for resources but this is a pretty unusual data set.

Comment: You can probably update your data to have a nested array. The first level is the unique values for `actual` then the second level is the values for the current `actual` value. Does that help?

Comment: @SamuelVaillant can you expound more by commenting some sample code?

Comment: Basically `[[18], [14], [7, 1]]` should do the trick. You don't have to put scalar value in it you can use an object but it gives you an idea about the structure that you could have.

Comment: So that's what you meant by a nested array. I see, thanks for this. I'll see if this helps

Comment: @SamuelVaillant I tried reading up on d3.stack() function, but I have no idea how to follow the array structure it produces. Also, I meant to put this on my last comment: I need to get the sum of the `actual` values as well